# Array[Byte] in Play Framework model

Tags: scala, playframework

I would like to ask you a question about byte array being part of the play framework model. My model is defined like this:

```
@Entity
class BTFile (
  @Required
  var hash : Array[Byte],

  @Required
  var size : Int

) extends Model {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="file",cascade=Array(CascadeType.ALL))
  var peers:JList[BTPeer] = new ArrayList[BTPeer]
}
```

With DAO object defined as

```
object BTFiles extends QueryOn[BTFile]
```

But every time i try to use BTFiles.find("byHash"), it throws following exception:

```
[B cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I tried to google it up but i found no solution. The unit test i test it in:

```
 it should "create and retrieve BTFile" in {
   val file = new BTFile("some_hash".getBytes,1).save

   BTFiles.find("byHash","some_hash".getBytes)

 }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try using `java.lang.Byte`, since `Array` is not type erased, and, therefore, and `Array[Byte]` cannot be cast into an `Array[Object]`.